# What is the grammatical construct of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

What is the grammatical construct of this sentence?

> We must be knit together as one man.

More text:

> "We must be knit together as one man," wrote John Winthrop, the first Puritan governor in America.

So, is `be knit together` a predicative? what about `as one man`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*We* is the subject. That makes the rest of the sentence the predicative.

*Must be knit* is the verb, with *must* and *be* auxiliaries. The sense of *knit* here is somewhat archaic, but we still use it to describe the regrowth of broken bones. *Together* is an adverb, indicating that the people in Winthrop's state must form a unified community.

The final prepositional phrase finishes the thought. Winthrop, somewhat optimistically, wants the citizens to be identical (*one man*) in some sense.